# Extracting part of lines with specific pattern using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a question regarding the `awk`/`sed` operators. I have a big file which has the following set of lines repeated

```
Expression loweWallrhoPhi :  sum=-6.97168e-09
Expression leftWallrhoPhi :  sum=6.97168e-09
Expression lowerWallPhi :  sum=-5.12623e-12
Expression leftWallPhi :  sum=5.12623e-12
Expression loweWallrhoUSf :  sum=-6.936e-09
Expression leftWallrhoUSf :  sum=6.97169e-09
Expression lowerWallUSf :  sum=-5.1e-12
Expression leftWallUSf :  sum=5.12624e-12
```

I want to extract the value after the keyword `sum` in each case into a separate file. Is it possible to do so at one go?

Answer (score 31):

#### With `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'sum=\K.*' inpufile > outputfile
```

grep with `-P`(perl-regexp) parameter supports `\K`, which use to ignoring the previously matched characters.

#### With `awk`:

```
awk -F"=" '{ print $NF; }' inputfile > outputfile
```

in *awk* the variable `NF` represent the total number of fields in a current record/line which is point to the last field number too and so `$NF` is its value accordingly.

#### With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^.*sum=//' inpufile > outputfile
```

`^.*=sum` replace all characters(`.*`) between starting of line(`^`) and last characters(`sum=`) with whitespace char.

Result:

```
-6.97168e-09
6.97168e-09
-5.12623e-12
5.12623e-12
-6.936e-09
6.97169e-09
-5.1e-12
5.12624e-12
```

#### With `cut`:

```
cut -d'=' -f2 inputfile > outputfile
```

---

if you want save same values into a same file and each separately, with `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F"=" '{print $NF >($NF); }' inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 6):

If I correctly understand the question you want to get only values after `=`, and store the these values in separate files, based on second field(?). If I'm right try something like this:

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '{print $6>"file_"$2".txt"}' file
```

The result:

```
$ ls -1
  file_leftWallPhi.txt
  file_leftWallUSf.txt
  file_leftWallrhoPhi.txt
  file_leftWallrhoUSf.txt
  file_loweWallrhoPhi.txt
  file_loweWallrhoUSf.txt
  file_lowerWallPhi.txt
  file_lowerWallUSf.txt

$ cat  file_leftWallPhi.txt
  5.12623e-12
```

Comment: @KasiyA I cannot reproduce your problem with GNU awk 4.0.2. The command from my answer works also with `-c` option (compatibility mode with traditional UNIX `awk` where GNU extensions are disabled). Please be sure you have updated input file as the original question was edited and empty lines deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it  by `sed`

```
sed -E 's/^.* (\S+)\s*:.*=(\S+)/echo "\2" > "\1".txt/' file | bash
```

The script find out two pieces in line:

1. between spaces and `:` and should contain some(more then 0) non-space symbols ;
2. some(more then 0) non-space symbols after `=`;

and format from its in execution command which transfered through the pipe to `bash`

Comment: A much more versatile answer.